# Set UIImageView.image between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to figure out... if I am in viewcontroller1 (VC1) and I have an NSTimer running so that after 100 seconds an image will get set in viewcontroller1 (VC2) and then I display VC2 (modal) after 10 seconds and wait another 90 seconds how can I, from the .m file of VC1 set the image on the VC (VC2) that is currently presented (and has been for about 90 seconds)?

I've found a few methods online (after an hour of searching) on how to set the image by passing UIImage with @property nonatmoic,retain ... but even then, all of this sample code just shows me how to set the data, I still would have to run a separate NSTimer or some other function in VC2 that is constantly checking to see if this variable has been updated, and then in VC2's .m I set the UIImageView's UIImage to the image (@property strong) that was passed.

In any event, in every case I could find, this is ALWAYS done during the "Prepare for segue" section...

Is there not a way from VC1's .m to change the image of a UIImageView in VC2? Or is the only way to change the UIImageView to actually do it from VC2's .m file following a `prepare for segue` from VC1?

---

In short, I want to change VC2's **UIImageView's image** from VC1... not change VC2's **UIImage** from VC1. And I want to do this WAY after I've segued to the new VC but I still have code running in the background int the old VC

Comment: I suppose you are using `UINavigationController`? In that way, it has a property called '-topViewController'. It will return instance of your VC2. You can do it in VC1. Then cast returned pointer (`UIViewController`) to VC2 class and use public interface to access `UIImageView` of your VC2. If you are presenting VC2 _without_ `UINavigationController`, you can get VC2 via `-[VC1 presentedViewController]` method

Comment: @art-divin Not using UINavController... I am interested in the second method you mentioned...  So in VC1 I say something like `[self presentedViewController].NameOfVC2ImageViewProperty.image = someUIImage;`

Comment: @art-divin But then, of course, I get an error saying that it doesn't know of a property named `.NameOfVC2ImageViewProperty` for UIViewController... so how do I use the method you mentioned? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for the VCs to communicate.  Most straightforwardly, VC1 can keep a pointer to VC2, and VC2 can provide public access to it's imageView.

This isn't particularly good design as it builds in dependencies between the two VCs, but here's how it would look:

```
// vc1.m
#import "VC2.h"

@interface VC1 ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) VC2 *myVc2;
@end

- (void)presentVC2 {
    // allocate init VC2 however you do that
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init // ...

    // keep a pointer to it
    self.myVc2 = vc2;

    // do whatever you do to present it, navigation vc push, or presentViewController, etc.
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

   // not sure from your question if you have the image at this point or if you
   // start a fetch for the image here.  let's say you have it
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimageinmyappbundle.png"];
   self.myVc2.publicImageView.image = image;
}
```

This works if VC2 provides public access to it's UIImageView like this:

```
// VC2.h
@interface VC2 : UIViewController

// assuming you painted it in a storyboard or xib
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *publicImageView;

@end
```

Please note, I'm not saying I like any of this, but it is the straightest line from point A to B.  A nicer pattern might be for VC1 to announce the readiness of the image with an NSNotification, and for VC2 to listen for that and set it's own image.  But the question appears to insist that VC1 does the work on the VC2 view hierarchy.

Comment: Setting the pointer to strong was what I missed... ARC kept getting rid of it haha! I just ended up using NSNotificationCenter instead.. works like a CHARM! And it's only one line of code on the main thread to send an object to ALL of my VCs!

Comment: Glad it worked, especially glad you chose NSNotificationCenter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can export (make a property) of your imageView, if you do not already do this.
Just note about your original assumption - if your image is a property, you can create your own setter, and do whatever you want when VC2 sets your image.